# Como fazer uma requisição POST com formulário JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá!
Estou tentando fazer uma requisição através de JavaScript, mas não estou conseguindo.

Preciso pegar o e-mail através de um formulário e enviar esse valor para a requisição, do tipo `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

No Postman eu coloco no body da seguinte maneira

`key: email
value: ["meuemail@com"]`

Como eu faço para pegar esse valor do input do formulário, transformar ele pra esse formato que preciso e enviar a requisição?

Meu código JS está assim:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("Bsubmit");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/request', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


btn.onclick = function() {
 request.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo:

```js
// Exemplo de requisição POST
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value; //Input texto com id "txtEmail"

// Seta tipo de requisição: Post e a URL da API
ajax.open("POST", "minha-url-api", true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// Seta paramêtros da requisição e envia a requisição
ajax.send("email=" + email);

// Cria um evento para receber o retorno.
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  
  // Caso o state seja 4 e o http.status for 200, é porque a requisiçõe deu certo.
 if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
    
  var data = ajax.responseText;
  
    // Retorno do Ajax
  console.log(data);
 }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! ^_^